# Xamarin forms android Application not getting DeviceToken Parse SDK

Tags: c#, android, parse-platform, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I'm developing xamarin forms application for both android and iOS. I'm implementing the PushNotifications for the same using Parse SDK. I've added Parse.Android dll in references of .Droid project and Parse.iOS dll in references of .iOS project. My problem is sometimes on Android I'm not able to retrieve the DeviceToken. There're no entries for DeviceToken and pushtype in the parse installation class. It's values are 'undefined'. Below is my code along with manifest.

```
public  async void RegisterForPushNotifications ()
    {
        try {
            if (Utility.isNetworkConnected ()) {
                await ParsePush.SubscribeAsync ("");
                var installation = ParseInstallation.CurrentInstallation;
                // I'm saving the DeviceToken in App.regId for future uses
                App.regId = System.String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace (installation.DeviceToken) ? "" : installation.DeviceToken;
                ParsePush.ParsePushNotificationReceived += PushNotificationReceived;
            }
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine (e.StackTrace);
        } catch (Java.Lang.Exception e) {
            e.PrintStackTrace ();
        }
    }
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" package="com.nirvaniclabs">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" android:targetSdkVersion="23" />
<application android:label="RxLifetime" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:largeHeap="true">
    <receiver android:name="parse.ParsePushBroadcastReceiver" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
            <category android:name="com.nirvaniclabs" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <service android:name="parse.ParsePushService" />
</application>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.LOCATION_HARDWARE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<permission android:protectionLevel="signature" android:name="com.nirvaniclabs.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.nirvaniclabs.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
</manifest>
```

Also some times above mentioned code is causing crashes at app startup. I've reported this issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32587891/parseinstallation-saveasync-causing-unhandledexception-on-xamarin-forms-androi) and [here](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/50689/parseinstallation-saveasync-causing-unhandledexception-on-xamarin-forms-android#latest)

Also `ParseClient.Initialize` is the very first line of 'OnCreate' method  of MainActivity where I'm passing parse keys required for initialization.

I'm calling RegisterForPushNotifications method after `LoadApplication (new App ())` is called.

Attached below is the screenshot of parse installation class.

[image: parse installation]

Please let me know if there's some issue in my code or is it the issue with parse SDK.

Comment: I guess you're not running in the emulator, right? The device receives only token in a physical device.

Comment: @iván-oliver The above mentioned issue is on physical device.

Comment: What do you mean by sometimes? The same device?

Comment: @Amrut I guess this question should be closed now, considering that Parse is shutting down anyways. Or are you still interested in an answer?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Parse SDK is deprecated now.

Answer (score 1):

when you have declare the push notification using xamarin then you have to write code on both section like xamarin android and IOS, and also if you have used to remote notification then use to push sharp lib which is a best for push notification and register your app and enable to notification service like GCM and APSN relevent to android and IOS.

Plese try this : https://github.com/rdelrosario/xamarin-plugins/tree/master/PushNotification/PushNotification